# How can I make a button that automatically click an anchor tag with a specific rel property?

Tags: javascript, html, button, anchor

I am trying to make a button that floats in the top right that clicks an anchor tag with the rel property set to "next". The tag's code is:
`<a href="website" rel="next"><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Next Post</span> Next Chapter</a>`

So far I have written this:

```
    var button = document.createElement("Button");
    button.innerHTML = "Next";
    button.style = "top:0;right:0;position:fixed;z-index: 9999"
    button.onclick = function(){
        var x = document.querySelector("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if(document.x[i].rel = "next"){
               window.location.href = x[i].href;
            }
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(button);
```

When I click the button generated though, it doesn't click the anchor tag. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you trying to iterate through the `.length` of an element?

Comment: I didn't know how else to get an anchor tag with res = "next" without going through every element and checking them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
var button = document.createElement("Button");
button.innerHTML = "Title";
button.style = "top:0;right:0;position:fixed;z-index: 9999"
button.onclick = function(){
  var x = document.querySelector("a[rel='next']");
  window.location.href = x.href;
}
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nharding/f3m6h74r/18/

Comment: It still brings me to an undefined page. The actual website link I am using to test this is "systemtranslation.home.blog/2019/12/20/i-d-w-a-t-s-chapter-18-must-eliminate-the-danger/". Thanks though.

Comment: what browser are you using? if I open that page in chrome and then open developer tools console and paste the above javascript it pops a button in the top right that I can click and it brings me to the "Two Sisters" page

Comment: I use chrome. When I used tampermonkey to implement the button, it didn't seem to work before, but I guess now it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.rel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement/rel) selector:

```js
const button = document.createElement("Button");
button.innerHTML = "Title";
button.style = "top:0;right:0;position:fixed;z-index: 9999"
button.onclick = function() {
  const link = document.querySelector("a").rel = "next"
  window.location.href = link.href;
}
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```html
<a href="https://systemtranslation.home.blog/2019/12/20/i-d-w-a-t-s-chapter-18-must-eliminate-the-danger/" rel="next"><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">Next Post</span> Next Chapter</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be bringing me to the next page. It is instead bringing me to an error page. The actual website link I am using to test this is "https://systemtranslation.home.blog/2019/12/20/i-d-w-a-t-s-chapter-18-must-eliminate-the-danger/".

Comment: I had used your same placeholder link whose href was just “website”. I’ve updated my answer now with the link you posted.

Comment: I am usng tampermonkey to implement this into the website. When I click the button, for whatever reason, it brings me to this page: "https://systemtranslation.home.blog/2019/12/20/i-d-w-a-t-s-chapter-18-must-eliminate-the-danger/undefined".